# getting error 'Invalid Column' in JPA while Fetching data using Join tables

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am getting Invalid Column name error when running my application. Below are attached log and entity and repo class.

When I run Select * query then it works but it does not work when I select certain columns.

```
select * from reorg_view_x x join resource_hierarchy rh on (rh.resource_id=x.faoi_rid)where not exists (select 1 from resource_hierarchy where resource_name =x.t_aoi)and x.region= :region and trunc (x.reorg_dt) = :reorgDt
```

I caanot use Select * because I need some column names only for my application. Please stick with JPA only.

**ERROR LOG**:

```
Hibernate: select distinct x.t_aoi resourceName, x.faoi_prid parentResourceId, rh.time_zone timeZone, rh.language language, to_date(created_dttm) from reorg_view_x x join resource_hierarchy rh on (rh.resource_id=x.faoi_rid)where not exists (select 1 from resource_hierarchy where resource_name =x.t_aoi)and x.region= ? and trunc (x.reorg_dt) = ?
{"logType":"DEBUG","logLevel":"WARN","logTimestamp":"2021-09-15T12:58:11.696-05:00","logger":"org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper","label":"SQL Error: 17006, SQLState: 99999","runtime":{"instance":"unknown","clusterName":"unknown","namespace":"unknown","image":"unknown","platformIdentifier":"AJSC7_JERSEY"},"application":{"deploymentUnitName":"com.att.dmp.ReorgResourceCreatorMs","motsApplicationAcronym":"MOTS_ID"}}
{"logType":"DEBUG","logLevel":"ERROR","logTimestamp":"2021-09-15T12:58:11.697-05:00","logger":"org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper","label":"Invalid column name","runtime":{"instance":"unknown","clusterName":"unknown","namespace":"unknown","image":"unknown","platformIdentifier":"AJSC7_JERSEY"},"application":{"deploymentUnitName":"com.att.dmp.ReorgResourceCreatorMs","motsApplicationAcronym":"MOTS_ID"}}
{"logType":"DEBUG","logLevel":"ERROR","logTimestamp":"2021-09-15T12:58:11.773-05:00","logger":"com.att.dmp.service.RestServiceImpl","label":"Exception in createAoi service:","runtime":{"instance":"unknown","clusterName":"unknown","namespace":"unknown","image":"unknown","platformIdentifier":"AJSC7_JERSEY"},"application":{"deploymentUnitName":"com.att.dmp.ReorgResourceCreatorMs","motsApplicationAcronym":"MOTS_ID"}}
```

***I have entity: ResourceHierarchy but not reorg_view_x***

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="resource_hierarchy")
public class ResourceHierarchy  {
    
      @Id
      @Column(name="RESOURCE_ID", nullable = false)
      private String resourceID;
      
      @Column(name="RESOURCE_NAME", nullable = false)
      private String resourceName;
      
      @Column(name="PARENT_RESOURCE_ID", nullable = false)
      private String parentResourceID;
      
      @Column(name="RESOURCE_TYPE", nullable = false)
      private String resourceType;
      
      @Column(name="TIME_ZONE", nullable = false)
      private String timeZone;
      
      @Column(name="LANGUAGE", nullable = false)
      private String language;
      
      @Column(name="EMAIL_ADDRESS")
      private String emailAddress;
      
      @Column(name="ORGANIZATION")
      private String organization;
      
      @Column(name="CREATED_BY")
      private String createdBy;
      
      @Column(name="CREATED_DTTM", nullable = false)
      private Date createdDttm;
      
      @Column(name="LAST_UPDATED_BY")
      private String lastUpdatedBy;
      
      @Column(name="LAST_UPDATED_DTTM")
      private Date lastUpdatedDttm;
      
      @Column(name="ACTIVE_FLAG")
      private String activeFlag;
      
      @Column(name="CAPACITY_TYPE")
      private String capacityType;
      
      @Column(name="DWA_FLAG")
      private String dwaFlag;

    public String getResourceID() {
        return resourceID;
    }

    public void setResourceID(String resourceID) {
        this.resourceID = resourceID;
    }

    public String getResourceName() {
        return resourceName;
    }

    public void setResourceName(String resourceName) {
        this.resourceName = resourceName;
    }

    public String getParentResourceID() {
        return parentResourceID;
    }

    public void setParentResourceID(String parentResourceID) {
        this.parentResourceID = parentResourceID;
    }

    public String getResourceType() {
        return resourceType;
    }

    public void setResourceType(String resourceType) {
        this.resourceType = resourceType;
    }

    public String getTimeZone() {
        return timeZone;
    }

    public void setTimeZone(String timeZone) {
        this.timeZone = timeZone;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public String getOrganization() {
        return organization;
    }

    public void setOrganization(String organization) {
        this.organization = organization;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDttm() {
        return createdDttm;
    }

    public void setCreatedDttm(Date createdDttm) {
        this.createdDttm = createdDttm;
    }

    public String getLastUpdatedBy() {
        return lastUpdatedBy;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedBy(String lastUpdatedBy) {
        this.lastUpdatedBy = lastUpdatedBy;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdatedDttm() {
        return lastUpdatedDttm;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedDttm(Date lastUpdatedDttm) {
        this.lastUpdatedDttm = lastUpdatedDttm;
    }

    public String getActiveFlag() {
        return activeFlag;
    }

    public void setActiveFlag(String activeFlag) {
        this.activeFlag = activeFlag;
    }

    public String getCapacityType() {
        return capacityType;
    }

    public void setCapacityType(String capacityType) {
        this.capacityType = capacityType;
    }

    public String getDwaFlag() {
        return dwaFlag;
    }

    public void setDwaFlag(String dwaFlag) {
        this.dwaFlag = dwaFlag;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ResourceHierarchy [resourceID=" + resourceID + ", resourceName=" + resourceName + ", parentResourceID="
                + parentResourceID + ", resourceType=" + resourceType + ", timeZone=" + timeZone + ", language="
                + language + ", emailAddress=" + emailAddress + ", organization=" + organization + ", createdBy="
                + createdBy + ", createdDttm=" + createdDttm + ", lastUpdatedBy=" + lastUpdatedBy + ", lastUpdatedDttm="
                + lastUpdatedDttm + ", activeFlag=" + activeFlag + ", capacityType=" + capacityType + ", dwaFlag="
                + dwaFlag + "]";
    }
      
      
      

}
```

I have **ResourceHierarchyRepository** like this

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.att.dmp.entity.ResourceHierarchy;

@Repository
public interface ResourceHierarchyRepository extends  JpaRepository<ResourceHierarchy, String> {

    
    @Query(value="select distinct x.t_aoi resourceName, x.faoi_prid parentResourceId, rh.time_zone timeZone, rh.language language, to_date(created_dttm) from reorg_view_x x join resource_hierarchy rh on (rh.resource_id=x.faoi_rid)where not exists (select 1 from resource_hierarchy where resource_name =x.t_aoi)and x.region= :region and trunc (x.reorg_dt) = :reorgDt", nativeQuery=true)      
    List<ResourceHierarchy> findAOI( @Param("reorgDt") String reorgDt,@Param("region") String region);
    

    
}
```

Do I need to create reorg_view_x entity as well and then fetch records in reorgViewX repository instead of doing them in ResourceHierarchy? But I think there are some other easy solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA cannot convert few selected columns to entities directly. Now here you have two options:

1. If you can write your query in `JPQL`, then you can use the constructor to build your object with few selected fields. Below is the minimal example:

   ```
   @Query("SELECT new ResourceHierarchy(fieldOne, fieldTwo) FROM ResourceHierarchy WHERE ... ")
   public List<ResourceHierarchy> method(String params, ..);
   ```
2. If you want to stick with the `native query`, then you must change the return type of repository method to `List<Map<String, Object>>`.

Comment: I did this ` List<Map<String, Object>>  rh  = resourceHierarchyRepository.findAOI(reorgDate,region);` Now I am getting output as `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap@8a3c16e` instead of records.

Comment: I am calling repo from here `List<Map<String, Object>>  rh  = resourceHierarchyRepository.findAOI(reorgDate,region);
  rh.forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: You cannot print the `Map` directly. Debug the contents of that `Map`.

Comment: From the `Map`, you will be able to access the fields using `alias` as a key.

Comment: After doing this I am being able to fetch records but it is not letting me to save. How can I fix this?

Comment: `public List<ResourceHierarchy> createAOI(String region, Date reorgDt)
 {
  List<Map<String, Object>> aois = Collections.emptyList();
  aois = resourceHierarchyRepository.findAOI(region,reorgDt);
  aois.forEach(map -> map.forEach((k, v) -> {
   logger.info(k + ":" + v);
  }));
  
  List<ResourceHierarchy> createdaois = Collections.emptyList();
  if (aois != null && !aois.isEmpty()) {
   logger.info("TO:DO : Need to create List !!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
  // createdaois = resourceHierarchyRepository.saveAll(aois);
  }
  return createdaois ;
 }`

Comment: there is problem in line `createdaois = resourceHierarchyRepository.saveAll(aois);` . saveAll does not work for that kind of List Map

Comment: Yes of course JPA `saveAll` does only work with `Entity`. You need to convert `Map` to `Entity` (here `ResourceHierarchy`) before saving it. You can use `ObjectMapper` for this conversion.